# Parse xml and a text file to remove wildcards in shell

Tags: xml, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have an xml file with input like this. I am trying to write a shell script to remove the wildcards in the host.

```
        <Group>
            <GroupEntry groupname="aM"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="*" name="root"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="*" name="apro"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="*" name="rock"/>
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <GroupEntry groupname="ESB"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="*" name="esbsvc"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="*" name="retryt"/>
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <GroupEntry groupname="Omega"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="*" name="omegauser"/>
        </Group>
   </GroupSet>
```

I have a text file that has hostnames for each of the groupnames as below.

```
aM
hostname1
hostname2

ESB
hostname3
hostname4

Omega
hostname5
hostname6
hostname7
hostname8
hostname1
```

I am trying to parse/go through the text file and change the xml file to remove the wildcards. So, the result i am trying to get is

```
        <Group>
            <GroupEntry groupname="aM"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="hostname1" name="root"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="hostname1" name="apro"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="hostname1" name="rock"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="hostname2" name="root"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="hostname2" name="apro"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="hostname2" name="rock"/>
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <GroupEntry groupname="ESB"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="hostname3" name="esbsvc"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="hostname3" name="retryt"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="hostname4" name="esbsvc"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="hostname4" name="retryt"/>
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <GroupEntry groupname="Omega"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="hostname5" name="omegauser"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="hostname6" name="omegauser"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="hostname7" name="omegauser"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="hostname8" name="omegauser"/>
            <GroupSubjectEntry host="hostname1" name="omegauser"/>
        </Group>
   </GroupSet>
```

I tried with sed and awk as the below example

`sed '/GroupSubjectEntry host="\*"/p' omegatest.xml|sed '0,/\*/s//host/'` but that's just changing the first line.

I thought of running this through a `for loop` and using `sed p` option but there's too many varaibles involved. I am basically trying to remove the wildcards in the xml to add appropriate hostnames.
Can someone please help?

Comment: IMHO experts always advise to use tools like `xmlstarlet` to parse xml files, so please do let us know if you have that in your box or you could install it. In case you couldn't install it then we could provide solutions as per that.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thanks for the response. Doesn't look like i have that. and i may not be able to install it on my servers.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming here. Also one more thing your very first line in groupname file `aM` should be there right? Could you please confirm it once.Also lines starting from `hostname` are really starting from hostname? Why asking this because we need some logic to pick values from file so wanted to check with you here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Sorry. that was a typo. i have corrected it. We have the text file however we want if it makes it easier for your logic. But the hostnames will have to go under the right groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with GNU `awk`. Fair warning tools eg--> `xmlstarlet` are recommended to deal with xmls since OP couldn't use those and doesn't have those so coming with this one but there is no guarantee that this will work with all kind of xmls, this has written strictly for shown samples only.

***1st solution:*** As per OP's expected output:

```
awk '
!NF{  next  }
FNR==NR{
  if($0 ~ /GroupEntry groupname="/){
     match($0,/"[^"]*/)
     val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
     match($0,/^ +/)
     spaces[val]=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
     namesVal[val]=$0
     next
  }
  if($0 ~ /<GroupSubjectEntry host=/){
     match($0,/name="[^"]*/)
     names[val]=(names[val]?names[val] ORS:"")substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)
     next
  }
  if($0~/<Group>/ || $0~/<\/Group>/){
    rest[++count1]=$0
  }
  next
}
!/hostname/{
  if($0 in names){
    nameVal=namesVal[$0]
    check=$0
    if(FNR==1){ print rest[++count2];found="" }
    print namesVal[$0]
    num=split(names[$0],arr,"\n")
  }
  if(found){ print rest[++count2];found="" }
}
/^hostname/{
  found=1
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    print spaces[check] "<GroupSubjectEntry host=\"" $0"\"  name=\""arr[i]"\"/>"
  }
  next
}
END{
  print rest[count2]
}
'  Input_file groupnames
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** If OP is NOT bothering of name sequence from actual Input-file then one could try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if(!NF){ next }
  if($0!~/^hostname/){ val=$0 }
  else               { arr[val]=(arr[val]?arr[val] ORS:"")$0 }
  next
}
/<GroupEntry groupname=/ && match($0,/".*"/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
}
/GroupSubjectEntry host=/{
  match($0,/^ +/)
  spaces=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  match($0,/name="[^"]*/)
  name=substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)
  num=split(arr[val],arr1,"\n")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    print spaces "<GroupSubjectEntry host=\"" arr1[i]"\"  name=\""name"\"/>"
  }
  next
}
1' groupnames  Input_file
```

Also this gives output in order of `hostnames` with respective entry of groupname, I hope OP is ok wit it.